# Find "Master coordinates" from multiple arrays with different block structures via slices

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have list of "blocks" of 3d-arrays in terms of slices,

e.g. `block1 = (slice(0,1),slice(0,4),slice(4,5))`

such that array(block1) would be the 1x5x1 block. Now some of these blocks overlap and I want to determine the "master blocks".

As an example, from the list

```
[[slice(0, 1, None), slice(1, 2, None), slice(0, 1, None)],
       [slice(1, 6, None), slice(2, 3, None), slice(0, 1, None)],
       [slice(1, 7, None), slice(2, 3, None), slice(0, 1, None)],
       [slice(1, 8, None), slice(2, 3, None), slice(0, 1, None)],
       [slice(6, 18, None), slice(3, 4, None), slice(0, 1, None)],
       [slice(6, 19, None), slice(3, 4, None), slice(0, 1, None)],
       [slice(8, 23, None), slice(3, 4, None), slice(0, 1, None)],
       [slice(8, 26, None), slice(3, 4, None), slice(0, 1, None)]
```

I want to find

```
[[slice(0, 1, None), slice(1, 2, None), slice(0, 1, None)],
       [slice(1, 8, None), slice(2, 3, None), slice(0, 1, None)],
       [slice(6, 26, None), slice(3, 4, None), slice(0, 1, None)]]
```

I didnt even come up with a working brute force solution. I tried comparing each block in the list piecewise and check whether it is contained in the other and delete the according obsolete block.

But this does not take into account when one block reaches from 1,6 and the other from 2,7 in the same dimension to give the "`master block`" 1,7 for this example.

Edit: I apologize, I think this problem is ill-posed because the solution is actually not a list of "master blocks" but just master coordinates because there is no real block structure, see the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to better illustrate the problem I came up with a funny solution myself:
All the 3d-arrays are of size (100,4,100). So I create dummy array and set all the blocks to a value

```
dummy = np.zeros((100,4,100))
for block in allblocks:
    dummy[tuple(block)] = 1
```

where allblocks is the list that has the overlapping blocks. If I set instead "dummy[tuple(block)] += 1" I can illustrate the overlap:

[image: overlap block structure]

Either way I can just use for example numpy.where(dummy>0) and I have what I actually needed.